# Comparar valores de array a number

Tags: php

Queria saber como puedo comparar el valor  de mi array $piezas que tiene 16 piezas con 4 valores cada una a cero, ya que haciendolo asi lo que me devuelve es 1111111111111111, es decir el numero de piezas que hay, muchas gracias

- hay 16 piezas (pieza[0]: 1, 4, 3, 2), asi son todas las piezas, solo quiero ver como recorrerlas y comparar sus valores a cero y cada vez que haya $piezas[$i][$j] == 0, se sume una unidad al contador, no hay mas script aprte de la declaracion del array inicial

```
  

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {

        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
           
            $contador = 0;

            if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){

                $contador++;
                echo $contador;
}
```

Comment: puedes poner el codigo donde llenas el array de valores?

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente en cada iteración se está dejando `$contador = 0;` y cuando encuentra un 0 el contador pasa a 1 e imprime 1 (luego en la siguiente iteración se vuelve a colocar `$contador = 0;`)

Solución: Definir `$contador = 0;` antes de los `for` :

```
$contador = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
        if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){
            $contador++;
        }
    }
}
echo $contador;
```

Recomiendo utilizar `foreach` y `in_array`:

```
$contador =0;
foreach($piezas as $pieza){
    if(in_array(0,$pieza)){
        $contador++;
    }
}
echo $contador;
```